# Why might I be getting an internal server error (500) on this http POST request

Tags: ios, json, swift, post, urlsession

I have been battling with this for ages. I am trying to upload an image to a server but keep getting a 500 error.

Here is the code I use to get the image, base64 encode it, and then add it to a dictionary.

```
 if let imageDataToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage, 1.0) {


            let encodedImageData = imageDataToUpload.base64EncodedString(options: [])

            let extras = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"

            let postBody = [
                "image": extras + encodedImageData,
                "id": id,
                "instruction": "1",
                "ext": ""
            ]

            let endPoint = UrlFor.uploadPhoto

            ApiManager().apiPostImage(endPoint: endPoint, postBody: postBody, callBackFunc: handleResultOfUploadPhoto) }
```

And here is the code I use to perform the actual POST request. You'll notice I am trying to convert the post body to a JSON object.

```
func apiPostImage(endPoint: String, postBody: [String: Any]?, callBackFunc: @escaping (ResultOfApiCall) -> Void) {

    // get the sessionKey
    guard let sessionKey = KeyChainManager().getSessionKey() else {
        print("error getting session key")
        AppDelegate().signUserOut()
        return
    }

    // create a url with above end point and check its a valid URL
    guard let url = URL(string: endPoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }

    // set up the request
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

    if let postBody = postBody {
        do {
            try urlRequest.httpBody = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postBody, options: [])
        } catch {
            print("problems creating json body")
        }
    }

    // set up the header
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    config.httpAdditionalHeaders = [
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "apiKey": "0101010-0101010", // not the real apiKey
        "usrKey": sessionKey,
        "appInfo" : "appcode:1000|version:2.0.37",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]

    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler:
        { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in

            let (noProblem, ResultOfCall) = self.checkIfProblemsWith(data: data, response: response, error: error)

            guard noProblem else {
                callBackFunc(ResultOfCall)
                return
            }

            let serializedData: [String:Any]
            do {

                // safe bc checked for nil already.
                serializedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]

            } catch  {

                callBackFunc(ResultOfApiCall.errorWhileSerializingJSON)
                return
            }

            // pass serialized data back using the callBackFunc
            callBackFunc(ResultOfApiCall.success(serializedData))
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

The API is RESTful. I don't have access to the API error logs, but I am getting this error back from the API:

```
["codesc": GENERALERROR, "code": 5001, "msg": Conversion from string "Optional(1004007)" to type 'Double' is not valid.]
```

Comment: what backend are you uploading too? do you have access to the error logs? what responses are you getting? try replicating the request to the backend using Chrome's postman app, if it works there then you know the problem is with the swift code. there isn't enough information here to provide an accurate answer

Comment: @Scriptable its a RESTful webservice. No I don't have access to the error logs. I am getting this error:Data from 500 error: ["codesc": GENERALERROR, "code": 5001, "msg": Conversion from string "Optional(1004007)" to type 'Double' is not valid.] I will update my question with this info.

Comment: do you get proper result when using any other rest client to do the api call?

Answer (score 0):

The 500 Internal Server Error is a server-side error, meaning the problem probably isn't with your computer or internet connection but instead is a problem with the web site's server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. Thank you to @Scriptable for pushing me to dig deeper for the error message being returned.

It seems the API was expecting a double for one of the properties, namely the id property, but I was passing in a String.

I also had to change the postBody Dictionary from an optional to non-optional.

Changed this and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var  task = URLSession().uploadTask(with: urlRequest, from: imageData) { (data , response , error) in
        // Check Response here
    })
```

`task.resume()`

The data you are sending is optional value, make sure the data you are passing is not optional value.